# How to change code::blocks default console

Tags: codeblocks

As I write quite a lot of console applications in code::blocks I was wondering if there was a more user-friendly way to do my IO. For example using cygwin or eclipse style console.

I've heard it is somehow possible through Tools, but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 7):

Settings->Environment Settings->"Terminal To Launch Console Programs:"

Answer (score 3):

Zabimaru already answered, but here's an example of changing from xterm to gnome-terminal on Linux.

Go to `Menu` > `Settings` > `Environment` > `General Settings` > `Terminal to launch console programs` and change the default

```
xterm -T $TITLE -e
```

to

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory --title $TITLE -x
```

which should actually appear as one of the drop-down options.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I fixed it.Just follow the below directions and you will get your code blocks to default state.

Goto view->perspectives-delete current.